# I want to use a self made Class in android

Tags: android

I am currently new to Android Development and i am having a difficult time trying to use a self made class in my MainActivity Android class.
Let me give you an example;
I created a SquareArea class and want to use it in the MainActivity Class

```
public class SquareArea{

  private double _length;
  private double _width;

  public SquareArea(double length , double width){
    _length = length;
    _width = width;
      area();   
  }

  private double area(){
    return _length
  }
}
```

When i instantiate the SquareClass in MainActivity class i want to be able to use the area() method and return when values that are Extracted from(EditText)
I want to use the value in order to place it in a text view;however this does not seem to happen.

I can do it with methods but i want to use my own classes instead.

Please help, I am getting frustrated with this.

```
///Below is my MainActivity Class///
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText mEditText1;
    EditText mEditText2;
    EditText mEditText3;
    TextView mTextView;
    Button mButton;
    Double value1, value2;
    SquareArea sq1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mEditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        mEditText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        mEditText1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        mEditText2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        mEditText3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);



        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //When the button is clicked, call the calucate method.
                //  calculate();
                try {
                    value1 = Double.parseDouble(mEditText1.getText().toString());
                    value2 = Double.parseDouble(mEditText2.getText().toString());
                    sq1 = new SquareArea(value1, value2);

                    mTextView.setText(sq1.toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    mTextView.setText("Please use numbers");
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `area() private`, so cannot you call it

```
public double area(){
     return _length
     }
```

and you just have to call your area()

```
mTextView.setText(String.ValueOf(sq1.area()));
```

Comment: @HoanNguyen.Thank you. Every Thing is working as expected.I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems

```
mTextView.setText(sq1.toString());
```

The toString method in SquareArea is not overridden. So the toString will return the default information about the object (location in memory, name, etc.)

```
public SquareArea(double length , double width){
    _length = length;
    _width = width;
      area();   
}
```

In the code above, you are inside the constructor. Why are you calling area() from here? A constructor can't return anything and the result from area() is being lost because area() returns a double.

And lastly:

```
private double area(){
  return _length
}
```

This method is private. It cannot be called from outside the class/object.

To make your code work this is what I would change.

```
public class SquareArea{

  private double _length;
  private double _width;

  public SquareArea(double length , double width){
    _length = length;
    _width = width;
  }

  public double area(){
    return _length * _width;
  }
}



///Below is my MainActivity Class///
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText mEditText1;
    EditText mEditText2;
    EditText mEditText3;
    TextView mTextView;
    Button mButton;
    Double value1, value2;
    SquareArea sq1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        mEditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        mEditText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        mEditText1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        mEditText2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        mEditText3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);



        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //When the button is clicked, call the calucate method.
                //  calculate();
                try {
                    value1 = Double.parseDouble(mEditText1.getText().toString());
                    value2 = Double.parseDouble(mEditText2.getText().toString());
                    sq1 = new SquareArea(value1, value2);

                    mTextView.setText(String.ValueOf(sq1.area()));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    mTextView.setText("Please use numbers");
                }
            });
        }
}
```